# Python 3x TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-files

I'm currently making a program which will compress a user sentence into two variables unique_words and positions. Unique words will be all the unique words from the user's sentence, so for example "the cat sat on the mat" the unique words will be "the, cat, sat, on, mat" and the positions will be 123415. I'm saving both of these in a text file.

I'm fairly new to coding, therefore I preferably would not want to use dictionaries as I believe it would make it so my code will not be able to keep capitalisation and punctuation.

Then what I want to be able to do is extract these back from the text file, and store them in two separate variables, so for example I want my code to look something like so:

```
list_1 = [the, cat, sat, on, mat]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
list_3 = []

for i in list_2:
  list_3.append(list_1[i])
```

However when I do this in my actual code:

```
for l in positions_File:
        orig_sntnce.append(uqwordsFile[l])
    print(orig_sntnce)`
```

I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
I think I need to somehow convert my list that contains the unique words into a 'slice'? I'm really stuck on how to do this? I've tried splitting the list but I think this would again, make it so I will not be able to keep punctuation and capitalisation of the original sentence.

Comment: Check the content of `positions_File`. It is not list of numbers, but list of strings. Probably you are having numbers in string format

Comment: You're reading `str`, so you have to convert it to an `int` with `int(l)`. Try `uqwordsFile(int(l))`.

Comment: You could use `uqwordsFile[int(l)]` to make sure that the index is an int, but probably you should check your input.

Comment: @NizamMohamed When I try uqwordsFile(int(l)) I get the error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I have changed my positions variable from string to integer now. I have also added in `uqwordsFile[int(l)]` however I am now getting the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `uqwordsFile` is a `list`. You must not call it. That's typo in my comment. use `uqwordsFile[int(l)]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried `               orig_sntnce.append[uqwordsFile[int(l)]]` but now I'm getting the error, `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` I'm not sure what this means? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -2):

list_1 elements should be strings i.e list_1 = ['the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'mat'], single quotes / double quotes are missing, and also see that the list_2 has 5 as an element which leads to an error because list_1 has only 5 elements and hence it can be indexed from 0,4 only.